# Как изменить стек на очередь (C++)

Tags: очередь

При вводе значений 1 2 3, программа выводит 3 2 1 (стек), что нужно подправить в методах ввода, чтобы при вводе 1 2 3 выводило так же 1 2 3 (очередь)?

```
class Ocher 
{

private:
    string* arr;
    string* top;
    string* bot;
    int size;

public:

Ocher(int s = 10) 
    {
        this->size = s;
        arr = new string[s];
        top = arr;
        if (bot==NULL) {bot=top;};
    }

Ocher(const Ocher& s) 
    {
        this->size = s.size;
        this->arr = new string[s.size];
        this->top = arr;
        string* p = s.arr;
        while (p < s.top) {*top++ = *p++;};
    }

bool isEmpty() 
    {
        if (top <= arr) 
        {return true;} else {return false;};
    }

bool isFull() 
    {
        if (top - arr >= size) {return true;} else {return false;}
    }

void push(string val) 
    {
        if(!isFull()) 
        {
            *top = val;
            top++;
        } else {cout << "Ochered polnaya!" << endl;};
    }

string pop() 
    {
        if(!isEmpty()) 
        {
            top--;
            return *top;
        } else {return 0;};
    }

void printOcher() 
    {
        string *p = top -1;
        while (p >= arr) {cout << *p-- << ' ';};
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы тупо развернёте данные при выводе, от этого стек в очередь не превратится. Вам придётся либо поменять структуру данных на связный список, либо почитать в интернете о том, что такое «кольцевой буфер».